# Why would the selfsame code instanciating PHPMailer work in one file/directory and not work in another?

Tags: object, phpmailer

The attached code works perfectly on our server.

FYI, the commented-out require() statement loads a file containing *every line of what follows it exactly.*

The problem occurs when I uncomment the require() statement and then comment out its identical contents below it.

When I do so, suddenly the PHPMailer object refuses to instanciate.

I have double-checked permissions for all files/folders and they are all fine.

This is a real head-scratcher.

HELP!

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require( CLASSES . "src/PHPMailer.php"  );
require( CLASSES . "src/SMTP.php"       );
require( CLASSES . "src/Exception.php"  );

//  require( 'receipt_email.php' );

$email = new PHPMailer();

try
    $email->IsSMTP();
    $email->SMTPDebug   = 0;
    $email->SMTPAuth    = TRUE;
    $email->Host        = SERVER_NAME;
    $email->SMTPSecure  = "tls";
    $email->Port        = "587";
    $email->Username    = MAIL_ACCTNAME;
    $email->Password    = MAIL_PASSWORD;
    $email->FromName    = "do_not_reply@lcus.edu";
    $email->From        = "LCUonline";
    $email->Subject     = "TEST MESSAGE";
    $email->Body        = "TEST MESSAGE BODY";
    $email->AddAddress( "developer@lcus.edu", "Dr. Steve Willis" );

    echo $email->Send() ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILED";
}

catch( Exception $e ) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$email->ErrorInfo}";
}

unset( $email );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't understand how `use` statements work. They are *local* aliases that apply *only* to the file in which they appear, [as the docs say](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php). So if you put them in one file, and have a namespaced class instantiation in another, it won't work, as you're finding. The separation in your case should be done like this:

In the first file:

```php
require( CLASSES . "src/PHPMailer.php"  );
require( CLASSES . "src/SMTP.php"       );
require( CLASSES . "src/Exception.php"  );

require( 'receipt_email.php' );
```

in `receipt_email.php`:

```php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
$email = new PHPMailer();
```

This, amongst other things, is why it's really worth learning how to use composer as it simplifies these things enormously.

Comment: I cannot use composer. Just tried. We are stuck on PHP v7.1 because of other software dependencies and composer requires v7.2.

So what else can I do to make this work?

Comment: Composer does not require PHP 7.2; it’s compatible right back to about PHP 5.4.

Comment: Then why did I receive a fatal error message stating what I just said?

Comment: I don’t know because you didn’t post the text of the error.

Comment: I added the use statements into the top of the require() file where the $email object is instantiated. Still fails!

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

$email = new PHPMailer();

Comment: The error message said composer doesn't support PHP versions less than v7.2 and that I am on v7.1

Comment: [composer’s official system requirements](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#system-requirements) say a minimum of PHP 5.3.2. It’s much more likely that you have a dependency that has some other PHP minimum, but we can’t help if you don’t post the actual error message. That code *by itself* will fail because it does not load the classes; that happens in the other script.

Comment: I made one change, invoking composer to autoload PHPMailer. composer autoload setup identical to another of our sites (which works). Fatal error; script halts. Error message states composer requires PHP >= v7.2; v7.1 installed. I remove the code invoking composer autoload of PHPMailer. Voila! Page works again. Ergo, there is no other software dependency breaking things.

Comment: I don’t know how many times I have to ask, but post *the full text of the actual error message* or we can’t help you. Also autoload.php is a file generated by composer; it is not composer itself.

Comment: Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.2.5". You are running 7.1.33. in /home/lcudevorg/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24

The only software installed under composer is PHPMailer

Comment: So just as I said, it’s not composer requiring that PHP version but one of your dependencies. If you post *the complete output from composer*, it will tell you which package that is. It’s worth checking that your version of composer is up to date; you should be running 2.x.